# dataTable, rowSelect and disable commandButton (JSF2.0 + Primefaces)

Tags: ajax, events, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a dataTable and I want the following behaviour:

I select a row and addRFI button is activated.

I push the addRFI button, it executes the addRFICustomer method and a ConfirmDialog appears.

I push the confirm button and the table doesn't have any row selected.

If it doesn't have row selected, addRFI button is not activated.

My code (MyCSR.xhtml):

```
   <h:form id="assignForm">   
      <p:dataTable var="csr" value="#{myCsrController.csrModel}" id="csrList" editable="true"  
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{myCsrController.csrSelected}" rowKey="#{csr.id}">

            <f:facet name="header">  
                My Work Page
            </f:facet>  

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myCsrController.onRowSelected}" update="addRFI,addTR" />  
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"  listener="#{myCsrController.onRowUnselected}" update="addRFI,addTR" />  

            <p:column headerText="CSR Number">  
                <h:outputText value="#{csr.csrNumber}" />  
            </p:column>
                 ...
            <f:facet name="footer">  
                <p:commandButton id="addRFI" value="Add/Remove RFI Customer" oncomplete="wdlg1.show()"  actionListener="#{myCsrController.addRFICustomer}" update=":assignForm:confirmDialog" disabled="#{!myCsrController.isSelected}" />  
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>      

        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" header="Add RFI Customer" widgetVar="wdlg1" message="Please confirm that an RFI Customer activity has been created for #{myCsrController.csrSelected.csrNumber}">       
            <p:commandButton id="confirmButton" value="Ok" oncomplete="wdlg1.hide()" update=":assignForm:csrList" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
```

MyCsrController:

```
  public void addRFICustomer(ActionEvent event){        
    ...
        }
  public void onRowSelected(SelectEvent event){ 
    setIsSelected(true);
}

  public void onRowUnselected(UnselectEvent event){ 
    setIsSelected(false);
}
```

My problem is that the method addRFICustomer is not executed, I think that when I push the addRFI button first disable the button and the actionListener is not executed... I would like to execute the listener first, What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any exception in the console? Put a p:messages component after the datatable and update it with the commandButton.
Do you get any messages?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you import ActionEvent with `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`.

I tried your code and find import ActionEvent with `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` may be your problem.

I used `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` in the beginning and the result is same as yours.

Try import `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`.